# ASP.DLL memory leak (or something) forcing constant restart of w3wp

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

We've been struggling with this for the past 12 or so months.  We think it's due to either one or two apps that are leaking memory or a large amount of leaks that have finally accumulated over years of programming in classic ASP.  We've begun the conversion to ASP.NET but we still have a large number of apps in classic.

We've tried changing how IIS restarts, depending on CPU and memory usage and we've tried to clean up some processes.  We've installed multiple analytical tools to be able to track exactly where it's coming from to no avail.

Just today we were able to finally track down a more detail error message, "Detected possible blocking or leaked critical section at asp!g Template cache+88 owned by thread 72 in W3WP".  It also states that "ASP.DLL is currently holding a Critical Section Lock on ASP template cache manager...".

[image: error screen]

So, is there any tool that will help track where our leak is coming from?  Or maybe a better way to restart this before it freezes our whole web process?

I appreciate your time!

Comment: What version of IIS? What server?

Comment: @JanuszJasinski IIS 7 and Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to use cache class (to html) for the most viewed pages look at http://www.webdevbros.net/2006/11/18/cache-object-for-classic-asp/.
2. You have to close all connections at the end of pages.

These will solve the memory leak.